# Hide unique divs when page loads. Can I create individual IDs for jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have developed a php loop that creates a register form everyday for each user in my database. Each form has one div which contains a variety of dropdowns (is blue) and this is placed directly over one  which shows has what has been submitted that day (is green). When one of the dropdown boxes is selected I have used jquery to make the top div disappear which shows the answer on the div below. If a mistake is made then there is a reset button which puts an x into the database and puts the blue div back on top.

I have also created a php query that finds the most recent input for each user every day (whether it is an x or what they were registered that day). This is then echoed into a div on to the top div (I use CSS to hide it).

What I want to have happen is that when somebody loads the page that it will show which people have already been registered that day. I want to do this by having a function that hides the top div for anybody who's string length is >2. I have tried multiple ways to do this but can't get any to work. Is there a way to create unique id's and then transfer these to jquery?

I have attached a simplified version of the code below that shows the two divs. Any help would be really appreciated. Essentially what I want to have happen is that when the page is loaded, if the text in div "top" is longer than 3 characters then that box disappears for that user and the green div below is shown. I am aware all the other programming is gone but I have sorted all of that and only need this to happen on load. I have tried using $(this) but it didn't work. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include 'dbconnection.php'; ?>
        <style>
            .show {visibility: visible;}
            .hide   {visibility: hidden;}
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".top").each(function() {
              if ($(this).text().length > 3) {
                $(this).parentsUntil(".bottom").addClass("hide");
                $(this).parentsUntil(".bottom").removeClass("show");
              }
            });
          }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * from firstnametest where class = 'group1'" );

     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>

    <div id="bottom" class="bottom hide" Style="background-color: green; width:398px; height:196px;">
        <div id="top" class="top show" Style="background-color: blue; width:398px; height:196px;">        
            <?php  echo$row["recent"];   ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Hiding green will automatically hide all blues (because they are children) so you likely never want to hide green.  Inside your onload if block try toggling the classes on `$(this)`, not `parentsUntil...`  It doesn't look like you need ids.

Comment: In the full code, the jquery I have used to submit the select option works and looks like this.  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".club").change(function(){
       $(this).parentsUntil(".bottom").addClass("hide");
        $(this).parentsUntil(".bottom").removeClass("show");
    });
});
</script>  When somebody selects an option which is in the "top" div it hides and shows the div below. Was hoping this would apply on load as well?

Comment: the `this` in your change function is not the same as the `this` within the each function.  In your each function you are iterating over all divs with class='top', which *are* the direct elements you need to hide (hence modify the classes of `$(this)` in the each function).

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. Can you suggest a way to get it to work?

Comment: `$(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');`